# IOException, Invalid Stream Header when using SealedObject.getObject()

Tags: java, ioexception, secret-key

I'm trying to use SealedObjects to send data over an RMI connection

target is a SealedObject, cipher is initialised beforehand (properly, as far as I'm aware), but when I run the following code, I get an IOException, with the message

```
invalid stream header: 52FAA4D1
```

Where 54FAA4D1 is a different 8 character hex string each time.

The code in question is

```
target.getObject(cipher);
```

Neither target nor cipher are null - so I presume that the problem is in how my cipher is set up. The key is created in exactly the same way on both the client and server, so I'm at a standstill.

The cipher is created using

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

//Do this to get the same parameters as were used on the client side
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.key);
AlgorithmParameters parameters = cipher.getParameters();

//Set to decrypt mode using the same parameters
byte[] iv = parameters.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

I've tried both with and without using the middle section, and neither seem to work.

If I remove the last parameter in cipher.init() the second time I call it I get an InvalidKeyException, and if I remove the middle section entirely and just use the cipher.getParameters.getParameterSpec(IVParameterSpec.class).getIV(); I get a NullPointerException

So yeah, completely stuck - any help appreciated on even understanding what the problem is would be appreciated.

Comment: What's going on with this line? `AlgorithmParameters cipher.getParameters();`

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for transcribing not copy+pasting. I actually set the variable parameters = cipher.getParameters(); (corrected above) in order to use the same parameters for decryption. I don't actually encrypt anything here - the encryption is done on client side: but I figured the parameters are the same as the key is the same?

Comment: I think something else is reading your cipher before the above code portion target.getObject(cipher).

Comment: With `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)`, I believe a random IV is generated to encrypt the message. You need to use the same IV on the server to decrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)` on the client, a random IV is generated. On the server, the first call to `ciper.init` is simply generating a different random IV which does not match the incoming message, so `getObject` only sees nonsense.

You need to use the same IV to decrypt each message as was used to encrypt it. In this case you can probably just prepend the IV to the cipher. Then read the IV into a byte array on the server and use it to initialize the decryption.

Comment: That might be working - although I can't tell if it's caused another error or just allowed me to stumble further through my code to one that already existed.... I'll investigate further.